# Getting column with days from first observed - trading data

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by, trading

So I have some Trading data, and ultimately I would like to find 1 week return 1 month, 3 month and so on. To do this I think it is easiest if I can get a column with days existed for each asset.

Data is simplified to this:

| Id | Date | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2014-09-14 | 0.7 |
| 101 | 2014-09-15 | 0.8 |
| 101 | 2014-09-16 | 0.9 |
| 101 | 2014-09-17 | 0.8 |
| 103 | 2014-10-03 | 1,6 |
| 103 | 2014-10-04 | 1.7 |
| 103 | 2014-10-05 | 1.7 |
| 103 | 2014-10-07 | 1.9 |
| 107 | 2015-10-17 | 24 |
| 107 | 2015-10-18 | 21 |
| 107 | 2015-10-23 | 22 |

I would then like an new column named "Days listed"

| Id | Date | Price | Days listed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2014-09-14 | 0.7 | 1 |
| 101 | 2014-09-15 | 0.8 | 2 |
| 101 | 2014-09-16 | 0.9 | 3 |
| 101 | 2014-09-17 | 0.8 | 4 |
| 103 | 2014-10-03 | 1,6 | 1 |
| 103 | 2014-10-04 | 1.7 | 2 |
| 103 | 2014-10-05 | 1.7 | 3 |
| 103 | 2014-10-07 | 1.9 | 5 |
| 107 | 2015-10-17 | 24 | 1 |
| 107 | 2015-10-18 | 21 | 2 |
| 107 | 2015-10-23 | 22 | 7 |

I think it needs to be grouped by id, but other than that I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use pd.groupby to get a earliest date for each group, which is then subtracted by the dates to get the days-listed

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['DaysListed']=(df['Date'] - df.groupby('Id')['Date'].transform('min')).dt.days+1
df
```

```
    Id  Date       Price    DaysListed
0   101 2014-09-14  0.7     1
1   101 2014-09-15  0.8     2
2   101 2014-09-16  0.9     3
3   101 2014-09-17  0.8     4
4   103 2014-10-03  1.6     1
5   103 2014-10-04  1.7     2
6   103 2014-10-05  1.7     3
7   103 2014-10-07  1.9     5
8   107 2015-10-17  24      1
9   107 2015-10-18  21      2
10  107 2015-10-23  22      7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""Id;Date;Price
101;2014-09-14;0.7
101;2014-09-15;0.8
101;2014-09-16;0.9
101;2014-09-17;0.8
103;2014-10-03;1.6
103;2014-10-04;1.7
103;2014-10-05;1.7
103;2014-10-07;1.9
107;2015-10-17;24
107;2015-10-18;21
107;2015-10-23;22
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=';')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(float)

df = df.assign(Days_list = df.groupby('Id').cumcount() + 1)
```

Output:

```
     Id        Date  Price  Days_list
0   101  2014-09-14    0.7          1
1   101  2014-09-15    0.8          2
2   101  2014-09-16    0.9          3
3   101  2014-09-17    0.8          4
4   103  2014-10-03    1.6          1
5   103  2014-10-04    1.7          2
6   103  2014-10-05    1.7          3
7   103  2014-10-07    1.9          4
8   107  2015-10-17   24.0          1
9   107  2015-10-18   21.0          2
10  107  2015-10-23   22.0          3
```